# Mono + SQLite + Dapper SQLite Exception during Insert

Tags: sqlite, mono, dapper

I am using Mono, SQLite, Dapper & Dapper Extensions. I can read from the database but Insert is not working. I am using Mono Driver for sqlite.

Error is not very informative, atleast to me. Any help will be much appreciated.

Error:

```
SQLite error
near ".": syntax error
at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection cnn, System.String strSql, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS,    System.String& strRemain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Test code:

```
public void can_add_a_service_record()
    {
        var provider = new Provider { Name = "Hotmail" };
        int id = providerData.Insert(provider);         
        Assert.AreEqual("Hotmail", providerData.Get(id).Name);  
    }
```

The code for insert is as follows.

```
public virtual int Insert (TEntity entity)
    {
        var connection = SqlHelper.GetConnection();         
        int id = connection.Insert<TEntity>(entity);
        connection.Close();
        return id;
    }
```

Thanks

Chirdeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks like a [Dapper Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) issue, not a Dapper issue. In particular, I can not see a Sqlite dialect implemented: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/tree/master/DapperExtensions/Sql .

To resolve I would recommend you submit a patch the the Dapper Extensions project (which is totally separate to Dapper) or use a different wrapper on top of Dappe, or use Dapper without a wrapper.

For example, the following should work:

```
var id = cnn.Query<int>("insert cars values(@name); select last_insert_rowid()", 
   new {name = "bmw"});
```

Comment: Right that makes sense. Thanks Sam.

Comment: Just a comment: Query<int> doesn't work on some platforms; you have to use Query<long>.

Comment: FYI: DapperExtensions now has a dialect for Sqlite (`DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new DapperExtensions.Sql.SqliteDialect();`)